# Not able to edit extern variables

Tags: c++, extern

I wrote the following code

head.h

```
int i = 0;
```

sample.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "head.h"

extern int i;
i = 20;

int main() {
    printf("%d \n",i);
    return 0;
}
```

when I compile sample.cpp the compiler is throwing the following error:

```
sample.c:5:1: warning: data definition has no type or storage class [enabled by default]
sample.c:5:1: error: redefinition of ‘i’
head.h:1:5: note: previous definition of ‘i’ was here
```

Answer (score 5):

It's the other way around, the `extern` declaration should be in the header and the definition in an implementation file and **defined only once**.

```
//head.h
extern int i;


//sample.cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include "head.h"

int i = 20;

int main() {
    printf("%d \n",i);
    return 0;
}
```

You can *declare* the variable as many times as you want, but the definition has to be unique.

Comment: If we declare that way and include the header in some other file, will both the files use the same extern variable? If the value of the variable is changed in one will it reflect in the other??

Comment: ok thank you. can you also tell me how extern and static variables differ in behavior in the case of a global variable.

Comment: @user1198065 static variables are not global, because a copy is created for every translation unit. If you have `static int a` and include that file in x.cpp and y.cpp, the two files will each have a separate copy of the variable.